# Меняю цвет заголовков и оглавления, но когда в Word нажимаю "обновить оглавление", цвет сбрасывается

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, com, ms-word

У меня есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую создаются пара заголовков, а потом, на их основе создается оглавление. Я меняю цвет заголовков, и меняю цвет оглавления, но потом, когда в файле Word нажимаю "обновить оглавление", установленный цвет оглавления сбрасывается. Как сделать так, чтобы цвет оглавления не сбрасывался, а оставался?

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  wrd:OleVariant;
  StartRange, tableOfContentsRange: Variant;
  tableOfContents: Variant;
begin
  wrd:=CoWordApplication.Create;
  wrd.Visible:=true;
  wrd.documents.add(EmptyParam,EmptyParam, EmptyParam,EmptyParam);
  wrd.Selection.Style := 'Заголовок 1';
  wrd.Selection.Font.Color := RGB(255,0,0);
  wrd.Selection.Text:='Первый Заголовок';
  wrd.Selection.MoveDown;
  wrd.Selection.TypeParagraph;
  wrd.Selection.Style := 'Заголовок 1';
  wrd.Selection.Font.Color := RGB(255,0,0);
  wrd.Selection.Text:='Второй заголовок';
  wrd.Selection.MoveDown;
  wrd.Selection.TypeParagraph;

  StartRange := wrd.ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0);
  StartRange.Font.Color:=RGB(0,255,0);
  tableOfContents := wrd.ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents.Add(StartRange);
  tableOfContentsRange := tableOfContents.Range;
  tableOfContentsRange.Collapse;
  tableOfContentsRange.Select;
  wrd.Selection.TypeText('Оглавление' + #13);
  tableOfContents.Update;
end;
```

Comment: Через Delphi, да и любой другой язык, поддерживающий COM, работать с Word-ом достаточно легко: в Word на закладке Вид-Макросы-Запись макроса. Выполняете ручками то, что нужно потом сделать программно. Останавливаете запись. Заходите в макросы и нажимаете "Изменить". Изучаете код VBA и портируете его в Delphi.

Comment: @kami, а не используя макросы, а только встроенные возможности Delphi, среди которых OleVariant и прочие, не знаете как все это сделать?

Comment: "Встроенные возможности Delphi", в частности - OleVariant - это и есть аналог макросов VBA. Например, в Delphi код `Word.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeText('фывафыва')` - аналог `Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeText Text:="фывафыва"` в VBA. Создание макросов помогает правильно составить код в Delphi, т.к. OleVariant "понятия не имеет" о синтаксисе объектов, которые он представляет.

Comment: Уточните свой вопрос, чтобы было понятно - что именно вызывает затруднения, тогда вам смогут предложить конкретные ответы. Крайне желательно - с вашим кодом, позволяющим понять, где именно у вас возникла проблема. Сейчас вопрос выглядит как слишком общий и одним из правильных ответов на него будет отсылка в гугл, поскольку примеров работы с Office из Delphi более чем много.

Comment: @kami, уточнил, добавил свой код

Comment: @lcnw Создайте 3 отдельных вопроса по каждому из своих трех пунктов в вопросе. Приведите в каждом из них часть своего кода, относящуюся к вопросу. И поясните, что конкретно не получается. Так вам будет проще формулировать вопросы, а нам будет проще разобраться в чем проблема.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, разбил на три вопроса, исправил этот

Comment: @lcnw так лучше )

Answer (score 5):

Все изменения, которые представлены в Вашем коде, применяются непосредственно к тексту. В вашем случае нужно изменять данные непосредственно у стилей, которым предстоит отображать оглавление (поскольку обновление оглавления практически "создает" его заново). Обратите внимание, что стили оглавления и стили основного текста - это разные вещи (хоть и могут ссылаться друг на друга), поэтому изменение одного *скорее всего* ни коим образом не повлияет на другое.

Ниже - переделанный метод с достаточно подробными комментариями:

```
procedure TForm8.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  wrd, Document: OleVariant;
  Selection: Variant;
  tableOfContents: Variant;
  TOC1Style: OleVariant;
begin
  // общий принцип - при работе с Word и другими приложениями из MS Office,
  // если какой-либо объект используется более 1 раза, то лучше
  // завести для него отдельную переменную и работать уже с ней.
  // иначе конструкции типа
  // wrd.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.блабла1
  // wrd.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Selection.блабла2
  // будут приводить к тому, что КАЖДЫЙ раз сперва будет вызываться wrd на предмет получения ActiveDocument,
  // потом ActiveDocument чтобы получить ActiveWindow ... ну и так далее.
  // Всё это, получаемое многократно, может замедлить и без того не быструю работу с MS Office.
  // Помимо прочего это в некоторой степени ограждает от действий пользователя
  // к примеру, пока работает ваша программа, пользователь может клацнуть по другому документу
  // соответственно wrd.ActiveDocument будет уже указывать не на нужный нам документ.
  wrd := CoWordApplication.Create;
  wrd.Visible := true;
  Document := wrd.documents.add;

  Selection := Document.ActiveWindow.Selection;

  Selection.Style := wdStyleHeading1; // для установки стилей лучше использовать
  // вот такие встроенные константы. Иначе есть риск напороться на иноязычный
  // Office,  в котором "верхний" стиль будет называться к примеру 'Header 1'
  Selection.Font.Color := wdColorRed;
  Selection.Text := 'Первый Заголовок';
  Selection.MoveDown;
  Selection.TypeParagraph;
  Selection.Style := wdStyleHeading1;
  Selection.Font.Color := wdColorRed;
  Selection.Text := 'Второй заголовок';
  Selection.MoveDown;
  Selection.TypeParagraph;

  // меняем стиль "Оглавление 1". В этом случае также лучше пользоваться константами.
  TOC1Style := Document.Styles.Item(wdStyleTOC1);
  TOC1Style.AutomaticallyUpdate := true;
  TOC1Style.Font.Color := wdColorGreen; // хочу зелененькое :)
  TOC1Style.Font.Italic := true;
  TOC1Style.Font.Bold := true;

  // создаем содержание
  tableOfContents := Document.TablesOfContents.add(
    Range := Document.Range(0, 0),
    RightAlignPageNumbers := true,
    UseHeadingStyles := true,
    UpperHeadingLevel := 1, // применяя стили заголовков от 1 (изменен нами)
    LowerHeadingLevel := 3, // до 3
    IncludePageNumbers := true,
    AddedStyles := '',
    UseHyperlinks := true,
    HidePageNumbersInWeb := true,
    UseOutlineLevels := true);

  Document.Range(0, 0).Select;
  Selection.TypeText('Оглавление' + #13#10);
  Selection.Move(wdStory, 1);

  tableOfContents.Update; // это излишне, содержание после создания
  // обновляется автоматически. Вот если бы мы после его создания
  // изменили основное содержимое, тогда да, обновить содержание не помешает.
end;
```