# Создание таблиц и диаграмм в Excel через Delphi

Tags: delphi, excel, com

Я заполнил несколько ячеек Excel данными, а теперь не могу на их основе сделать диаграмму. Ругается на тип Chart и на xlColumns. Что не так?
И можно ли заполнять ячейки данными через цикл?

```
procedure TForm1.btn4Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  E,b,Chart:OleVariant;
  i:Integer;
begin
  E:=CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  E.Visible:=True;
  E.Workbooks.Add;
  E.Range['A1']:='1';
  E.Range['A2']:='2';
  E.Range['A3']:='3';
  E.Range['A4']:='4';
  E.Range['A5']:='5';
  E.Range['B1']:=Sin(1);
  E.Range['B2']:=Sin(2);
  E.Range['B3']:=Sin(3);
  E.Range['B4']:=Sin(4);
  E.Range['B5']:=Sin(5);

  Chart:=b.Charts.Add;
  Chart.ChartType:=xlLineStacked;
  Chart.SetSourceData(Source:=E.ActiveWorkbook.Sheet.Item[1].Range['A1:E5'], PlotBy:=xlColumns);
end;
```

Comment: Приведите конкретные сообщения об ошибках, в вопросе пожалуйста.

Comment: @KromStern, а можете показать валидный код? Писал код по учебнику, и не понимаю как решить этот вопрос

Answer (score 3):

Поскольку этот вопрос [перекликается](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/497759/192901) с предыдущим в плане навыков программной работы с приложениями MSOffice (да и вообще с COM-объектами), попробую объяснить порядок составления своего Delphi-кода на основе VBA. Напоследок отложим непосредственно ответ на сам вопрос.

Во-первых, нужно представлять себе иерархию объектов MS Office-приложения. В Excel она несколько проще, чем в Word.

Основное:

```
- Application - глобальный объект, из него можно "достучаться" до чего угодно   
    - Workbooks - коллекция книг,
      (Workbook) - каждая из которых содержит
        - Worksheets - коллекцию рабочих листов
          (Worksheet) - на которых мы и размещаем информацию.
               - Cells - ячейки листа. Именно с ними и производится бОльшая часть работы - 
                         размещение данных, объединение/разделение, изменение шрифта и т.п.
```

Собственно, по большому счету все. Остальное запоминать не обязательно, потому что мощным помощником выступает сам Excel/Word, позволяя записывать все "ручные" действия пользователя в макросы.

**Приступим**. Первый этап - размещение данных на нужном листе. Здесь пользуемся приведенной ранее иерархией:

```
var
  Excel, Book, Sheet:OleVariant;
  i:Integer;
begin
  Excel:=CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  Excel.Visible:=True;
  Book:=Excel.Workbooks.Add;
  Sheet:=Book.Worksheets[1];
  for i := 1 to 5 do
    begin
      Sheet.Cells[i, 1].Formula:=i;
      Sheet.Cells[i, 2].Formula:=Sin(i);
    end;
```

Замечательно то, что большинство свойств принимает тип Variant, то есть - практически любые значения: строки, integer, Double и т.п.

Есть [несколько способов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197454.aspx) задать значение ячейке: `Formula`, `FormulaR1C1`, `Value`, etc. Нужно понимать их различия и пользоваться необходимыми соответственно задаче. Чаще всего используются именно `Formula` и `FormulaR1C1`

Так же полезно понимать, что каждая ячейка на самом деле это объект [Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx), то есть представляет собой любое, произвольное количество ячеек и работа с несколькими ячейками из состава `Range` не отличается от работы с одной ячейкой, полученной через `Cells`.

**Далее** необходимо на лист добавить график. Мы не знаем, как это сделать, да и из-за однократности задачи помнить, где этот график находится в иерархии объектов - расточительно.

Заходим в меню "Вид", нажимаем "Макросы - Запись макроса" и нажимаем "ОК". Переходим на вкладку "Вставка" и добавляем простую гистограмму. Далее выбираем дипазон данных (я взял `B1-B5`), изменяем подписи (выбрал `A1-A5`) подтверждаем изменения и останавливаем запись макроса ("Вид" - "Макросы" - "Остановить запись"). Теперь осталось войти внутрь макроса ("Вид" - "Макросы" - "Макросы"-"Изменить"). Должен получиться примерно такой код VBA:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("B1:B5")
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Лист1!$A$1:$A$5"
```

И вот тут нам понадобится [справка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238877%28v=office.12%29.aspx), потому что дальше не все так тривиально. Разберем по строчкам:

`ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select` - последний метод (`Select`) нас не интересует, поскольку он просто выделяет добавленную фигуру на листе. Для программной работы выделение объекта излишне. А вот `AddChart` добавляет объект `Shape`, а нам нужен объект Chart. VBA дальше идет по пути наименьшего сопротивления - использует свойство [Application.ActiveChart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196586.aspx) (`ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered` и т.п.). Но нам это не подходит, поскольку (повторюсь) при программной работе с Excel нежелательно использовать "активные элементы", нужно работать именно с тем, что мы добавили. Выясняем, что у объекта Shape есть свойство [Chart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb225658%28v=office.12%29.aspx), именно оно нам нужно. Соответственно, всю дальнейшую работу строим именно на этом, переводя код VBA в Delphi:

```
    Shape:=Sheet.Shapes.AddChart; // повторюсь - Select нам не нужен.
    // но при желании потом можно сделать Shape.Select
    Shape.Chart.ChartType := xlColumnClustered; // вместо ActiveChart - наш Shape.Chart
    Shape.Chart.SetSourceData(Source:=Sheet.Range['B1:B5']);
    Shape.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues := Format('=%s!$A$1:$A$5', [Sheet.Name]);
```

Здесь следует обратить внимание, что мы избегаем называть возможно локализованное имя листа (оно может зависеть от языка Office, пользователь может его переименовать и т.п.). Поэтому берем реальное наименование из свойства Sheet.Name.

**Вот и все.** Полный получившийся код:

```
procedure TForm8.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Excel, Book, Sheet, Shape:OleVariant;
  i:Integer;
begin
  Excel:=CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  Excel.Visible:=True;
  Book:=Excel.Workbooks.Add;
  Sheet:=Book.Worksheets[1];
  for i := 1 to 5 do
    begin
      Sheet.Cells[i, 1].FormulaR1C1:=i;
      Sheet.Cells[i, 2].FormulaR1C1:=Sin(i);
    end;

  Shape:=Sheet.Shapes.AddChart;
  Shape.Chart.ChartType := xlColumnClustered;
  Shape.Chart.SetSourceData(Source:=Sheet.Range['B1:B5']);
  Shape.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues := Format('=%s!$A$1:$A$5', [Sheet.Name]);
end;
```

**В заключение** замечание по поводу используемых констант `xlColumnClustered` и подобных: можно подключить в uses модуль `Excel2010`, `ExcelXP` или другой, имеющийся в вашей версии Delphi. Но можно и подставлять значения констант вручную, через поиск в Google (лучше брать ссылки на первоисточник - microsoft). Например, поиск по `xlColumnClustered` первой же ссылкой дает перечень констант [XlChartType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241008%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`Chart:=b.Charts.Add;` до этой строчки в `b` нужно что-то положить, оно у вас пустое. Возможно, там должно быть `E` вместо `b`.