# Как подвинуть график в Excel на определенную ячейку?

Tags: delphi, excel

У меня есть график в Excel, который мне нужно подвинуть на определенную ячейку.

По идее код должен быть примерно такой:

```
procedure TMyExcelClass.MyProcedure;
var
  sheet, chartObject: Variant;
begin
  sheet := fExcel.ActiveWorkBook.Sheets['какой-то лист'];
  chartObject := sheet.ChartObjects[1];
  chartObject.Left := <левая граница ячейки "F">
  chartObject.Top := <верхняя граница ячейки "34">
end;
```

Как правильно позиционировать график к границам ячейки? (с учетом того, что ячейки могут иметь разную ширину и высоту)

Comment: 34 * (ширина ячейки + ширина рамки ячейки). Так же с высотой.

Comment: @slippyk неверно. Ячейки могут иметь разную ширину и высоту. Добавил это в вопрос.

Comment: @Kromster Запиши в excel макрос и посмотри как он это делает.

Comment: Chart содержится внутри Shape. У Shape есть свойства Left и Top, позиционирующие относительно левой-верхней ячейки листа. Left и Top можно взять прямо у нужной ячейки: `Sheet.Cells[i, j].Left`. Не стоит работать с `ActiveWorkbook` и т.п. из `Application.ActiveXXX`. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/499795/192901

Comment: @kami нашел решение одновременно с вашим комментарием. Если запостите как ответ - приму ваш.

Comment: @Kromster не стоит, пусть остается ваш. Но еще раз обращу внимание - уйдите от использования ActiveWorkbook и т.п. Глюков можно поймать, если пользователь переключится на другую книгу/другой лист.

Comment: @kami Спасибо! Уйти пока не могу. Но на будущее, подскажите, в какую сторону уходить, куда копать?

Comment: Вы же открываете/создаете книгу? Соответственно, используете `Application.Workbooks.Add` или аналоги. Это - функция, и она возвращает ссылку на книгу. Соответственно - присваиваем результат в свою переменную `myWorkbook` и дальше работаем именно с `myWorkbook`, а не с `ActiveWorkbook`. По аналогии - с листом.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37877951/how-to-position-element-chart-in-excel-to-a-certain-cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов ([предложенных тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37881530/77764)) взять диапазон, у него есть свойства Left и Top.

```
procedure TMyExcelClass.MyProcedure;
var
  sheet, chartObject, r: Variant;
begin
  sheet := fExcel.ActiveWorkBook.Sheets['какой-то лист'];

  r := sheet.Range['F34'];

  chartObject := sheet.ChartObjects[1];
  chartObject.Left := r.Left;
  chartObject.Top := r.Top
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Свойство `Left` ([объекта Shape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197987.aspx)) типа `Single` задает расстояние в точках от левого края объекта до левого края столбца `A` (на листе) или левого края области диаграммы (на графике). [Аналогично](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840384.aspx) свойство `Top` от верхнего края листа.

Таким образом, чтобы задать нужную позицию графика(диаграммы) относительно конкретной ячейки нужно сложить ширину всех ячеек слева от нужной и сложить высоту всех строк выше нужной.

Comment: "сложить ширину всех ячеек слева от нужной"  .. оверкил какой-то. Мой вариант гораздо проще.

Comment: Согласен, ваше решение куда элегантней.