# Как сохранить и получить служебную информацию в TWordApplication?

Tags: c++, delphi, ms-word

При открытии документа необходимо сохранить служебную информацию (свои данные, такие как id документа и т.п.), и в случае когда пользователь решил сохранить документ - получить эту информацию. Есть событие `WordApplication1DocumentBeforeSave` где мне необходимо получить эту служебную информацию. Как это осуществить?

Comment: Что из свойств документа ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/ff840898.aspx ) вы считаете "служебной информацией"? особенно интересует ID.

Comment: служебная информация это внутренние переменные, которые никак не связаны с свойствами этого компонента. Мне достаточно хотя бы знать, где мне ее хранить, чтобы в событии WordApplication1DocumentBeforeSave я смог бы ее получить, чтобы идентифицировать сохраняемый документ. В обычных компонентах есть свойство например tag, которое системой никак не используется, и отлично бы подошла для подобных целей. Здесь увы, такого нет.

Comment: То есть, вам  нужно добавить свои данные непосредственно к документу? Если да - то из вопроса это не очевидно, стоит его уточнить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь свойством документа [CustomDocumentProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/office/ff195603.aspx)

В приведенных по ссылке примерах как раз рассматривается получение и установка не регламентированных свойств.
Единственное замечание - лучше заранее получить ссылку на сам документ, а не использовать свойства типа `ActiveDocument`

**Upd**. Простой пример, правда выполненный на Delphi:

```pascal
procedure TForm2.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  msoPropertyTypeNumber = 1;
  msoPropertyTypeBoolean = 2;
  msoPropertyTypeDate = 3;
  msoPropertyTypeString = 4;
  msoPropertyTypeFloat = 5;
var
  App, Doc: OleVariant;
begin
  App:=CoWordApplication.Create;
  App.Visible:=True;
  Doc:=App.Documents.Add;

  // добавляем два своих свойства.
  Doc.CustomDocumentProperties.Add(Name:='myProp1', LinkToContent:=False, Value:='11111', Type:=msoPropertyTypeString);
  Doc.CustomDocumentProperties.Add(Name:='myProp2', LinkToContent:=False, Value:='2222', Type:=msoPropertyTypeString);

  // и выводим их в Caption формы.
  Caption:=Doc.CustomDocumentProperties[1].Value + 
    // значение первого - получаем по индексу
    Doc.CustomDocumentProperties['myProp2'].Value;
    // а второго - по имени.
  App.Quit;
end;
```

Comment: В теории кажется то что нужно! Но на практике пока реализовать не получилось. На примерах используется метод Add для добавления кастомных свойств, у себя я его не обнаружил. Само свойство CustomDocumentProperties принимает только значения типа IDispatch *. Пока что копаю в эту сторону.

Comment: @Mikage на практике - тоже, если не пользоваться TWordApplication, а использовать OLEVariant. В качестве примера работы - ссылка на мой же ответ (не сочтите за рекламу:)  ) http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/499557/192901 Через OleVariant все методы "подхватываются" в runtime, позволяя ко всему прочему указывать - какие параметры выставить в явном виде, а какие оставить по умолчанию - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/498288/192901 (пример из Excel, но это не важно).

Comment: @Mikage я дополнил ответ примером использования.